# Two Column Div Layout in Wrapper - Why is one getting pushed down?

Tags: html, css

url: http://www.5vforest.net/#portfolio

```
#portfolio .projectWrapper{
width: 100%;
float: left;
}

.projectLeft{
font-size: 10pt;
padding-top: 10px;
margin-right: 500px;
}


.projectRight{
width: 500px;
text-align: right;
float: right;
}
```

No idea why this isn't working.... I'm totally stumped. Any advice? Thanks.

Comment: What you want to achieve by doing this.. Please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it work by moving `<div class="projectRight">..</div>` to before `<div class="projectLeft">..</div>` in the HTML.

Comment: Whoops, thought I had tried that already, guess not. Thanks a bunch, worked like a charm.

Comment: Could you please answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10141148/css-two-column-div-layout-misaligns-when-zoom-changes ?

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no space for it. Project left has a `500px` margin right which is pushing it down.

```
.projectLeft {
    font-size: 10pt;
    padding-top: 10px;
    width: 500px; // other div must have fluid space, thanks thirtydot
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: I *think* the idea is that `.projectRight` takes `500px`, and `.projectLeft` is fluid and takes the remaining space.

Answer (score 0):

both columns should float:

```
.projectLeft{
font-size: 10pt;
padding-top: 10px;
float:left;
//the width you need
width: 500px

}


.projectRight{
width: 500px;
text-align: right;
float: right;
}
```

Comment: solved with thirtydot's solution. projectLeft needs to have a fluid width.